# Is the mean life being 1/$\lambda$ a coincidence or a definition?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

We were studying radioactivity and after we worked out the half life to be $ln2/\lambda$ the professor then said, this is the average time it takes for half the nuclei to decay to find the average time for 1 nuclei to decay its just $1/\lambda$.

Is there some statistical proof to this or is this just a definition.

Comment: Depends on your definitions. Usually $\lambda$ is defined as the inverse of the mean life. How was $\lambda$ defined in your class?

Comment: The proportionality constant between the number of nuclei and the rate of decay.
i.e $\lambda N= dN/dt$

Comment: So you're asking for a proof starting with that differential equation?

Comment: If possible, yes.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, suppose the cumulative distribution function of the time for a single nucleus to decay is $P(t)$, then the half life $T_{1/2}$ will satisfy $P(T_{1/2})=1/2$, and the average time for a nucleus to decay is $T_0=\int_0^\infty t(1-P(t))dt$ .

In the case of radioactive decay, or any other exponential decay, we know that $P(t)$ has the form $P(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$, based on the observation $-dN/dt\propto N$. Calculation shows that $T_0=1/\lambda$ and $T_{1/2}=\ln2/\lambda$.